# Python create folder for each file in a directory

Tags: python

I have a directory with a set of files in it. I'm trying to create a folder for each filename inside the existing directory, and name it the given filename. but i'm getting an I/O error permission denied... what is wrong with this code?

```
import os

path = "C:/Users/CDGarcia/Desktop"

os.chdir(path)

gribs = os.listdir("testgrib")
print gribs

print os.getcwd()

if not os.path.exists(os.path.basename("gribs")):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("gribs"))
with open(path, "w") as f:
    f.write("filename")
```

Comment: Can you try executing the code on different path than desktop ?

Comment: no I have not yet, but I can try that. didn't think it would make a difference

Comment: @John's suggestion won' t fix your problem but its a very good idea to debug this script in a temporary directory. Your script has many problems and at some point while you are sorting them out you run the risk that `with open(path, "w") as f:` will truncate all of the files on your desktop. Don't practice with live ammunition!

Comment: You create a list called `gribs` but then start processing a string `"gribs"`. Didn't you want to enumerate the files in `gribs` and process them? ... after moving to a temp directory of course.

Answer (score 1):

[`os.path.dirname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) does not do what you expect it to do. It returns the directory name for the path you pass to it. So it interprets whatever string you pass as a path. As such, when you pass a path that has no directory part, it returns an empty string:

```
>>> os.path.dirname("gribs")
''
```

So with `os.makedirs()` you are trying to create an empty directory, which of course will not create the path you are looking for.

Instead, you should just use `os.makedirs('gribs')` to create `gribs` folder relative to your current directory.

---

Furthermore, `open(path)` will not work when `path` is the path to the desktop directory. You will have to pass a path to a file there. You probably meant to use a file path relative to the folder you create there:

```
with open('gribs/something.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write('example content')
```

Comment: so I made the changes, but i'm still getting a permissions error..? Will it not work on the desktop?

import os

path = "C:/Users/CDGarcia/Desktop"

os.chdir(path)

gribs = os.listdir("testgrib")
print gribs

print os.getcwd()

if not os.path.exists(os.path.basename("gribs")):
    os.makedirs('gribs')
with open('gribs', 'w+') as f:
    f.write('subdata')

Comment: You should include the full error message, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: sorry.. it says IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'gribs'

Comment: You’re still trying to open `gribs`, the folder.

Comment: So I got the script to work, by appending the output folder names with '.subdata'... When i tried to name the folders with the physical file name, i would get an error saying "the file already exists"... i ended up using the following code (which though isn't what i ultimately wanted to achieve, will work for me):

import os

path = "C:/CHRIS/testfolder/testgrib"
gribs = os.listdir(path)
grib = gribs

os.chdir(path)
print os.getcwd()


for folder in grib:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, folder + '.subdata'))